# Webview doesn't support picture resizing

Tags: android, image, android-webview

I'd like an Activity to show an edited version (a lighter one) of a web page taken from a web site; well the Webview widget works fine except for one thing: it can't show resized pictures. I'll be more clear: when I edit the web page source code I resize (changing the values of width and height) the pictures and the media to fit into the screen; but then, when I call the loadData method the picture have always the same size...it's driving me crazy. This is a web page badly rendered:

```
    <html> <head> </head> <body> <div class="submitted">
          Inserito da Andrea Francesco Berni<br />31 ottobre 2011 - 23:57           
      </div><div class="content">
    <p>A poche settimane dalla premiere mondiale del film dei <a href="/film/i-muppet">Muppet</a>, la Disney ha preparato alcuni divertenti materiali per festeggiare la ricorrenza di <strong>Halloween</strong> con i simpatici pupazzi di <strong>Jim Henson</strong>.</p>
<p>Si tratta di due immagini e di uno spot, ovviamente tematizzati: nella prima foto Fozzie presenta un mucchio di battute dedicate ad Halloween, mentre nella seconda vediamo una e-card parodia: &quot;La moglie di Kermitstein&quot;!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="rtecenter"><img alt="" src="http://www.badtaste.it/sites/default/files/images/varie/2011/muppet_fozzie.jpg" style="width: 465px; height: 355px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" /></p>
<p class="rtecenter"><img alt="" src="http://www.badtaste.it/sites/default/files/images/varie/2011/muppet_frankermit.jpg" style="width: 465px; height: 355px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Qui sotto, invece, potete vedere lo spot in italiano, nel quale <a href="/film/i-muppet">I Muppet</a> augurano buon Halloween tutti i fan:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<center><iframe width="465" height="261" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-s6cKQAFHcE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>  </div></body> </html>
```

what is wrong with it? when I load this using android the pictures are always as big as the original version...help me please!

Comment: What version of Android are you using? On Gingerbread, when loading the above html into a webview control I can see the images changing size/dimensions by adjusting the height and width of the images. e.g. changing the width: 465px  to: 233px halves the image width on the webview.